# How to save static transforms in bag files?

Tags: rosbag, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I save a static transform in a bag file so I get a self contaned bag file that can be replayed?

Not it seems like for example rviz do not understand a static transform in a bag file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207551/how-to-save-static-transforms-in-bag-files?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-06-02**:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/706 is a related issue- the tf_static is only recorded in the first bag when splitting bags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Finally a nice option exists a few years later :)**

This is covered by [this issue](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/706) on Github. The [corresponding PR](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1850) has been merged over a year ago and `Noetic` is shipped with the feature. It does so by repeating the latched topics (e.g. static TFs) for each bag.

The option you are looking for while recording is `--repeat-latched`, so e.g.:

```
 rosbag record -a --repeat-latched --duration 5 --split
```

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) with karma: 212 on 2022-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you record `/tf` and `/tf_static` topics that should capture all the tf data.

Edit:

@TommyP You're right, there is a problem that rosbag doesn't record/reproduce the latched topics. This is additionally a problem in that if you have multiple latched publishers, the latching is per publisher and if it all comes from rosbag that's a problem as only the latest message will be latched.

The recording side of rosbag is probably adaquate, but for full functionality a node which aggregates the static transforms published by rosbag and republishes them would be needed. My suggestion would be to create that node which will aggregate the static transforms subscribed to something like `/tf_static_consolidated` publishing to the usual `tf_static` topic and remap the rosbag play `/tf_static` to the consolidated topic when playing back.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2015-04-23**:
But rosbag play is problematic. It seems to publish the static transform once so all programs like rviz that you happen to start after starting playing the file will not get the static transform. Shouldn't rosbag play publish the static transforms on a latched topic?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2015-04-23**:
My mistake. It seems to be published on a latched topic. So I wonder why we had strange problems with rviz.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-04-26**:
As I mentioned you probably had trouble since latching is per publisher, and since rosbag is a single publisher I expect that you lose some of the values if you logged multiple static transform publishers.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2015-04-26**:
That sounds reasonable. Good to know that there is a design issue here and not just us using things wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was also bitten by this -  ([and a solution is not on the horizon](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/109#issuecomment-525458511)).

As an alternative to the accepted answer, another workaround is to replicate the static tf transform as a standard tf message through the bag. For example every time another transform of your interest is published. [Here](https://gist.github.com/marcoesposito1988/d6964fb85f9f8c35326489def444e7f6) is a brief python script that achieves this. You can replace the 'world' link with the one you need.

In my case, this made the updated bag work out-of-the-box. I hope anyone else can find this useful.

---

Originally posted by [marcoesposito1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/7591/marcoesposito1988/) with karma: 191 on 2019-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1